# OpenJDK 13/jpackage - Problem with bundled application and runtime under windows

Tags: java, jlink

I'm testing the jpackage utility in OpenJDK 13 to create bundles and installers. Works great on Windows and MacOS as long as I use OpenJDK as runtime for the created bundle. But OpenJDK13 is not released and I like to use OpenJDK12 as runtime.
So I'm creating a OpenJDK12 runtime with:

```
jlink --output myruntime 
    --module-path ../jmods 
    --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH 
    --bind-services 
    --compress=2 
    --strip-native-commands
```

And I use this runtime in jpackage with

```
jpackage create-app-image ^
    -o "/MyProject" ^
    -i /MyProject/path/to/my/jars ^
    -n application ^
    --runtime-image ..\..\OpenJDK12\bin\myruntime ^
    --main-class my.application.main.class ^
    --main-jar main.jar
```

Bundles are created without errormessage. But when I try to start the application I get an error "Failed to launch JVM" under Windows.

If I try the same on MacOS everything works fine.

Does anybody have an idea or some tipps what is wrong? Or where I can search for a solution or more informations?

Thanks